# What are the issues with using a general purpose motor on a variable frequency drive?

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors

What happens in this scenario - a modern electrical motor, three phase, squirrel cage, that is not specifically designed for operation via frequency inverter, *is* in fact operated on an FI? How long will the motor last, compared to 50Hz only operation? How will it fail (if at all)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience there are three main failure modes for motors on a VFD. These modes of failure are more likely when the motor is not rated "Inverter Duty". However note that when used properly on a high quality VFD, a general purpose motor will usually last LONGER on a VFD than without due to smoother acceleration, current protection, voltage protection, torque limiting options, and mechanical harmonic frequency avoidance.

1. Insufficient cooling. Heat is the primary killer of motors in my experience. Generally an induction motor is cooled by a small impeller mounted to the shaft. At 50Hz(full speed Europe) or 60Hz(full speed US) this provides sufficient cooling for the windings and bearings. When you continuously operate on a VFD at low RPM there is not sufficient cooling. Even inverter-duty motors with industrial grade safety factors should not be operated below 20Hz without supplemental fan cooling. For a non rated motor it would be better to not drop below 30Hz without supplemental cooling. Even with supplemental cooling you would never want to use a general purpose motor for very slow control with vector or sensor-less vector control; it would most certainly burn up.
2. Electrical noise and voltage spikes. Engineers minimize electric motor winding insulation thickness to get more power in a smaller lower cost package. Since general duty electric motors have less insulation, the windings can arc and fail from voltages spikes due to the fast IGBT switching in the VFD. Inverter-grade motors have thicker insulation resulting in a larger form factor, higher cost, but better protection (but not invincible) to voltage spikes. The best way to reduce this is to buy a high quality VFD (I recommend Yaskawa). Another way to help reduce these spikes is to add a line filter and/or ferrite beads on the lines.
3. Eddy currents. This failure mode is less common but on lower quality VFDs (Allen Bradley lol), the electrical noise that is generated from the IGBTs switching on and off at high frequency can cause a charge to build up on the rotor of the motor that then discharges through the bearings quickly destroying them and causing them to burn up even on industrial grade motors. One solution is to have new ceramic bearings pressed into the motor for $$$. The best solution is just to by a good VFD in the first place (Yaskawa). Another possible option that we did not explore is adding a grounding graphite brush to the output shaft.

A good article on these topics from [automation direct.](https://www.automationdirect.com/products/motors/index)

Comment: I'll wait a day or two before accepting, ping me if I forget!